# Are there other games that support simultaneous local+online multiplayer on the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

**Context**

I play games on the Nintendo Switch with several friends who are geographically separated. Two of my friends live in the same home and only have one Switch between them. We regularly play Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, which allows for us to connect online, in addition to the two people in the same home sharing a console to play split-screen.

In an effort to expand our collection of games we can play together, we have been trying to find other games that support this functionality. Stardew Valley, with the most recent update, supports local split-screen multiplayer, and online multiplayer, but not a combination of the two. Luigi's Mansion 3 implies that it supports local plus online co-op, but it's only in a small portion of the game using the "Gooigi" mechanic in a time trial mode. Similarly, I've read that Mario Party doesn't support the full board game in online multiplayer mode, only playing the minigames.

**Question**

If Mario Kart 8 Deluxe isn't the only game to support this functionality, is there a way to see a list of such games in the Nintendo eShop, or another site that has compiled a list of them?

Answer (score 1):

Diablo three also offers simultaneous local and online multiplayer, though definitely not a game for everyone. I would suggest searching for local multiplayer or online multiplayer Nintendo Switch games and then doing some more in-depth research.

Also, Minecraft supports simultaneous local and online multiplayer, so long as everyone you want to play with has a Switch Online account. You could play survival or party up on servers.